# Mysql server in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want  use  WSL for my Ruby on rails application with Mysql database. I am not sure where should I install mysql server??
In Windows or wsl (Ubuntu)?

Can anyone please tell where mysql server will install?

Comment: You can install MySQL either inside or outside of WSL. A Windows install will let you use a graphic installer/frontend, while installing it inside of WSL will be slightly easier to connect to.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1536619/connect-to-mysql-from-wsl2

Answer (score 0):

you can use an sql server installed anywhere as long as you can connect to the machine from where your application is running

Comment: Thanks, but if I install it on Windows than how can rails application know that it need to use mysql server from Windows?

Comment: just set your host to localhost/127.0.0.1, I believe that should work

Comment: So what I understood is, we can install mysql server in Windows or wsl. And by host name (127.0.0.1) rails identify database. Correct me please if I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I installed MySQL through WSL Ubuntu. Mostly because I had issues setting up PostgreSQL, got frustrated, moved to MySQL and used a program like DB Beaver or SQL Workbench to explore. You can also use VS Code with plugins to explore and work with databases.

I much prefer working in WSL2 and using everything within Linux instead of trying to cross from Linux to Windows and back to Linux.

Just my opinion. Hope